# axios request to localhost Error: connect ECONNREFUSED using Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions

axios request error in firebase cloud function. here is my code.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import axios from 'axios';

export const mobileDoUpdate = 
functions.firestore.document('/users/{ID}')
.onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {


axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user?id=29&status=active')
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.url);
    console.log(response.data.explanation);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});

});
```

the error is showing me Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
how can I solve it? help me please.

Comment: is your server running @8000 port?

Comment: my laravel backend project is running on port 8000

Comment: check this `http://localhost:8000/user?id=29&status=active` in your web browser. if you are not able to check it in the browser then there is some issue in larval server code

Comment: also check the backend console and see if your backend endpoint gets hit.

I don't think it will be the case but you can check this discussion as well.
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/543

Comment: Thanks, I've checked with postman to this api is still working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't make requests to localhost when running on Cloud Functions.  That's never going to work.  You're going to need a full proper URL for the host or service you're trying to contact, and it's certainly not going to be localhost.  localhost always means IP address 127.0.0.1, which is the same machine where the request is originating.  Once you've deployed this code, localhost becomes the Cloud Functions server instance where the code is running, not your desktop machine.

Comment: Thank, I'll try with that.