# Access local services from firebase cloud functions emulator (ECONNREFUSED connecting to localhost)

Tags: node.js, firebase, docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-functions

Obviously Firebase Cloud Functions cannot access http services on localhost, once deployed ([as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56852764/1918059)). However, is there a way to test local http services when running the **cloud functions emulator** locally?

I have a node.js app and various firebase emulators running in docker containers (with docker-compose), all using different ports. I need my cloud function to send a POST request to the node app, and I'd like to test this all on my local machine.

The cloud function (hosted at http://0.0.0.0:3318) gets an ECONNREFUSED error when I attempt to post a request to my node app (at http://localhost:2018) using axios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the magic of docker-compose networking, I found I could connect to my node.js service (named `api` in my `docker-compose.yml`) from my emulated function simply using the url `http://api:2018`